# Merging Tibbles, but overriding missing values

Tags: r, join, merge, na, tibble

I'm joining the following two tibbles using `full_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

tibble(id=c(1:2, NA), b = c("mouse", "cat", "fish"), c = 6:8) %>% 
full_join(tibble(id=1:3, b = c("mouse", "", "fish"), c = 6:8))
```

This will give me:

```
A tibble: 5 x 3
 id     b     c
 1 mouse     6
 2   cat     7
NA  fish     8
 2           7
 3  fish     8
```

Ideally though, I would like to get something like that:

```
A tibble: 5 x 3
 id     b     c
 1 mouse     6
 2   cat     7
 3  fish     8
```

Where all NAs or missing values are being replaced by a more "superior" row that has more information. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your specific example, I think your question is how to combine two tibbles while each of them has different incomplete observations (rows). Before conducting `full_join`, you can clear your data a little bit by using `filter_all`.

```
filter_all(all_vars( (!is.na(.)) & (.!="") ) )
```

So it means to select row that meet two conditions (for all variables): is not NA and "".

```
tb1 <- tibble(id=c(1:2, NA), b = c("mouse", "cat", "fish"), c = 6:8) 
tb1 <- tb1%>% filter_all(all_vars((!is.na(.))&(.!="")))
> tb1
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   id    b         c
  <int> <chr> <int>
1     1 mouse     6
2     2 cat       7
```

Do the same thing for the anther set and then do the `full_join`.

```
tb2 <- tibble(id=1:3, b = c("mouse", "", "fish"), c = 6:8)
tb2 <- tb2 %>% filter_all(all_vars((!is.na(.))&(.!="")))
full_join(tb1,tb2)
Joining, by = c("id", "b", "c")
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id b         c
  <int> <chr> <int>
1     1 mouse     6
2     2 cat       7
3     3 fish      8
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two `tibbles` are called `a` and `b`, we can first replace any character considered as missing values to be `NA` (in this case, "" is considered to be `NA`). `b[b == ""] <- NA` is a quick way to do this.

After that, we can do `full_join` by the column you know is complete (in this case, column `c`). Finally, we can use the `coalesce` function to replace `NA` with two associated columns. `dat` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

# Create example data frame
a <- tibble(id=c(1:2, NA), b = c("mouse", "cat", "fish"), c = 6:8)
b <- tibble(id=1:3, b = c("mouse", "", "fish"), c = 6:8)

# Replace "" with NA
b[b == ""] <- NA

# Conduct full_join by c
dat <- full_join(a, b, by = "c") %>%
  # Use coalesce to merge column and replace NA
  mutate(id = coalesce(.$id.x, .$id.y),
         b = coalesce(.$b.x, .$b.y)) %>%
  # Select columns
  select(id, b, c)

# View the results
dat
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      id b         c
#   <int> <chr> <int>
# 1     1 mouse     6
# 2     2 cat       7
# 3     3 fish      8
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `safe_left_join` from my package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin), and use
    `dplyr::coalesce` to handle the column conflicts.

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)

a <- tibble(id=c(1:2, NA), b = c("mouse", "cat", "fish"), c = 6:8)
b <- tibble(id=1:3, b = c("mouse", "", "fish"), c = 6:8)
```

solution:

```
b[b==""] <- NA
safe_left_join(a, b, by = "c", conflict = coalesce)
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      id b         c
#   <int> <chr> <int>
# 1     1 mouse     6
# 2     2 cat       7
# 3     3 fish      8
```